# Getting css background-size height number of img after change

Tags: jquery, css

```
var $img='<img id="_img"src="large.png"style="display:none;"/>';
$('body').prepend($img);
$img.load(function(){
    if(this.width>$(window).width()){$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'100% auto'});}else
    if(this.width<$(window).width()){$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'100% auto'});}
if(this.height>$(window).height()){$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'auto 100%'});}else 
if(this.height<$(window).height()){$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'auto 100%'});}
                if(this.width<$(window).width()&&this.height<$(window).height()){
if(this.width>this.height){$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'100% auto'});}
else{$('#_64b'+n).css({'background-size':'auto 100%'});}
    $('#_img').fadeIn(500);
}
```

I'm not understanding how to get the new background-size in px after the css background-size **'resize'**

If I knew that then I think I could ask JavaScript to put background-position something like:

```
//if the height is bigger than width

var css_height=?; //unknown number

var same_posx_new_posy='0px '+(($(window).height()-css_height)/2)+'px';

$('#_img').css({'background-position':same_posx_new_posy});
```

Correct?

**Dang!!** I've just realized that I'm not dealing with a background as-in

```
<div style="background:url('whatever.png');">
```

I'm using images instead because the load event is better with

```
$img.load(function(/*do stuff*/){}).each(function(){
   var t=setTimeout(function(){if(&&(this.complete){$(this).load();}},1000);//handles cahing nicely
   });
```

So is my Jquery css manipulation idea stupid or what?

Comment: css can automatically resize the image width to fill the page...
background: url(image1.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed ; 
there are options to resize the width and height in css also...

Comment: Please try to clarify your question and remove the irrelevant parts dealing with the `background-position` since you aren't dealing with backgrounds